# How to access getdbo in joomla api/plugin?

Tags: web-services, api, plugins, joomla

I am creating web services/api in joomla for my mobile app to access.

When I try to create object of database using...

```
$db = &JFactory::getDbo();
```

I get error as..

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method ClassName::getDBO() in <Path> on line 108
```

My queries are,

Can we access joomla library functions or database function in plugin/api?

If yes How?

If no why?

Comment: What version of Joomla or Joomla Platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can access the library and database functions externally but you need to import the relevant sections first.

```
//init Joomla Framework
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).DS.'..'.DS.'..'.DS.'..'));

require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');
```

should do it nicely. Then call

```
//DBQuery
$database =& JFactory::getDBO();
```

and go from there!

Comment: Thanks George Wilson :)
That helped a lot.